# How do I use CSS3 transitions to fade in on hover?

Tags: css

I set this up: http://jsfiddle.net/yWHfK/

However, I can't get it to fade in on hover. Any ideas where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've listed your transition element as color (which will transition the text color), did you mean to make it background-color?

ie

```
a { -moz-transition:background-color .2s ease-in;-o-transition:background-color .2s ease-in;-webkit-transition:background-color .2s ease-in;background-color:#31c3e7;text-decoration:none }
#post-list { color:#fff;text-align:center }
#post-list li { border-bottom:1px solid #4d4949 }
#post-list li a { color:#fff;display:block;font-size:16px;padding:20px 0 }
#post-list li a:hover, #post-list li.current a { background-color:#3c3636 }
#post-list li a:active {  }
#post-list li a span { font-size:12px }
```

That works for me in Chrome.

Comment: Don't forget to append `transition: background-color .2s ease-in;` for both future releases and current browsers that already implement the W3C spec (such as Opera).

Answer (score 0):

you ought to do this:

```
.class li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}
```

you can change  the #fff to whatever colour you want.